# Calling a C function from Assembly -- switching calling convention for functions with more than 6 args?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, nasm, calling-convention

I have an assembly application for Linux x64 where I pass arguments to the functions via registers, thus I'm using a certain calling convention, in this case `fastcall`. Now I want to call a C function **from the assembly application** which, say, expects 10 arguments.

Do I have to switch to `cdecl` for that and pass the arguments via stack regardless of the fact everywhere else in my application I'm passing them via registers? Is it allowed to mix calling conventions in one application?

Comment: Have you read the [ABI specification](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/elf/x86-64-abi-0.99.pdf)? It says there how to deal with functions that take more arguments than registers available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that by *fastcall*, you mean the amd64 calling convention used by the SysV ABI (i.e. what Linux uses) where the first few arguments are passed in `rdi`, `rsi`, and `rdx`.

The ABI is slightly complicated, the following is a simplification. You might want to read [the specification](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/elf/x86-64-abi-0.99.pdf) for details.

Generally speaking, the first few (leftmost) integer or pointer arguments are placed into the registers `rdi`, `rsi`, `rdx`, `rcx`, `r8`, and `r9`.  Floating point arguments are passed in `xmm0` to `xmm7`. If the register space is exhausted, additional arguments are passed through the stack from right to left. For example, to call a function with 10 integer arguments:

```
foo(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, k);
```

you would need code like this:

```
mov $a,%edi
mov $b,%esi
mov $c,%edx
mov $d,%ecx
mov $e,%r8d
mov $f,%r9d
push $k
push $i
push $h
push $g
call foo
add $32,%rsp
```

For your concrete example, of `getnameinfo`:

```
int getnameinfo(
    const struct sockaddr *sa,
    socklen_t salen,
    char *host,
    size_t hostlen,
    char *serv,
    size_t servlen,
    int flags);
```

You would pass `sa` in `rdi`, `salen` in `rsi`, `host` in `rdx`, `hostlen` in `rcx`, `serv` in `r8`, `servlen` in `r9` and `flags` on the stack.

Comment: @Kooiomo Do you have trouble understanding gas syntax? If so, I can translate the examples for you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course. Calling convention is applied on per-function basis. This is a perfectly valid application:

```
int __stdcall func1()
{
   return(1);
}

int __fastcall func2()
{
  return(2);
}

int __cdecl main(void)
{
  func1();
  func2();

  return(0);
}
```

Comment: if I take `getnameinfo` from C, do I have to pass **all** the arguments via stack to it when calling from Assembly? or am I allowed to pass part of them via registers and part via stack? or all arguments via registers?

Comment: @Kooiomo See my answer.

Comment: @fuz, that doesn't exactly answer my 3 questions.

Comment: @Kooiomo I see. Which question remains open?

Comment: @fuz, all 3 remains. "do I have to", "am I allowed"

Comment: @fuz, what if I wanted to pass all of them via stack? or all of them via registers? of 1 via register and the rest via stack? or 1 via stack and the rest via registers? or 2 of them stack and the rest via registers? and so on. Would it be **possible** to do so regardless whether or not it's faster?

Comment: @Kooiomo You can't do that, the function expects the arguments in certain places as I explained, if you put them elsewhere the function won't work correctly. The ABI is a rule, not a suggestion. However, in your own code you can of course write functions that expect its parameters in arbitrary places; just don't expect the compiler to be able to call that function.

Comment: @fuz. ok. however, why don't you use the registers below r8 -- r7, r6, r5...., is it according to ABI?

Comment: @Kooiomo There are no registers named `r1` to `r7` on amd64.

Answer (score -2):

You can, but you don't need to.

`__attribute__((fastcall))` only asks for the first two parameters to be passed in registers - everything else will anyhow automatically be passed on the stack, just like with `cdecl`. This is done in order to not limit the number of parameters that can be given to a function by chosing a certain calling convention.

In your example with 10 parameters for a function that is called with the `fastcall` calling convention, the first two parameters will be passed in registers, the remaining 8 automatically on the stack, just like with standard calling convention.

As you have chosen to use `fastcall` for all your other functions, I do not see a reason why you'd want to change this for one specific function.

Comment: 1) not eax, but rax. 2) why? there're r1-r10 registers for x64 Linux.

Comment: OP specified x64, `fastcall` isn't standardized and your example is MS implementation not Sys V which would utilize at least RDI and RSI as first and second argument.